# Выбор правильной архитектуры отношений классов

Tags: python, django, архитектура

[image: диаграмма классов]

Допустим, имеем базовый класс комнаты чата *Room*. Он в свою очередь подразделяется на 2 подкласса *RoomTypeA* и *RoomTypeB*. От этих классов уже наследуются конкретные реализации. Притом, есть класс пользователей комнаты *RoomMember*, который ссылается на *Room* по ForeignKey.

---

Описание проблемы: имея экземпляр (`room_member = RoomMember()`), обращаясь через связь к комнате и вызывая её метод `room_member.room.do_staff()` необходимо, чтобы выполнялся метод конкретной реализации комнаты (например, *ConcreteRoomTypeA_1*).

---

Сейчас написано решение, что в базовом классе *Room* в поле *concrete_room_class_name* сохраняется название класса конкретной комнаты, которая создалась. И когда я хочу через `room_member.room` вызвать метод `do_staff` я через `__subclassess__` рекурсивно спускаюсь в потомки класса *Room*, пока не найду класс, название которого совпадает со значением в поле *concrete_room_class_name* и вызываю метод `do_staff`. Мне очень не нравится эта реализация. Как сделать эту работу правильно?

Не думаю, что абстрактные классы - мои помощники здесь, ибо тогда не получится иметь только один класс *RoomMember*.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Room:
    R = {}
    def __init__(self, t): Room.R[t] = self
    @classmethod
    def do_staff(cls, t): cls.R[t].do_staff()

class RoomTypeA(Room): pass
class RoomTypeB(Room): pass

class ConcreteRoomTypeA_1(RoomTypeA):
    def __init__(self, t='A1'):
        RoomTypeA.__init__(self, t)
    def do_staff(self): print('->A1')

class ConcreteRoomTypeB_1(RoomTypeB):
    def __init__(self, t='B1'): RoomTypeB.__init__(self, t)
    def do_staff(self): print('->B1')

class RoomMember:
    def __init__(self, room): self.room = room

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = ConcreteRoomTypeA_1()
    b = ConcreteRoomTypeB_1()
    room_member = RoomMember(Room)
    room_member.room.do_staff('B1')  # "->B1"
```

Comment: Подскажете, где почитать про профит встроенных декораторов аля @ classmethod? Из того, что читал - нифига не системно написано. @vadim-vaduxa

Comment: Я незнаю такой ссылки. Когда, зачем и какой профит от его использования, это тема отдельного вопроса. Задайте его, и получите гораздо более исчерпывающий ответ от всех участников, чем я мог бы дать вам в комментарии.

Comment: @vadimvaduxa Когда в базе создаётся новая запись о ConcreteRoomTypeA_1, то сначала создаётся в таблице Room (id, к примеру, 12). Далее в RoomTypeA создаётся с id=12, потом в ConcreteRoomTypeA_1 с id=12. Можно ли избежать дополнительный полей\переменных, а использовать как-нибудь факт с id? Ибо в процессе выполнения кода я как раз не знаю, к какой Rom относится RoomMember и нельзя вписывать конкретные параметры (B1, A1). p.s. все классы - модели django.